# Slow querying inside a list of references in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I'm saving a log of searches in the website in MongoDB via Morphia and using Play 2. The log has the usual query term and list of results. So basically like this:

```
public class SearchLog {

    public String query;

    @Indexed
    @Reference(lazy = true, ignoreMissing = true)
    public List<Result> results;

    @Indexed
    @Embedded
    public LocalDateTime timestamp;

}
```

I build a query based on when the searches were done and whether the results contain "this" like so.

```
Query q = q().filter("timestamp >=", start).filter("timestamp <=", end)
    .field("results").hasThisElement(something).order("timestamp").asList();
```

There are about 8000 log entries in the database with each log containing ~10-20 Results. This particular query I'm testing returns about 4000 entries. However, the query is extremely slow (>10 sec) even with Index. Did I do anything wrong/is there a way to optimise how MongoDB do the query?

Thanks

Comment: What indexes are on the collection?

Comment: The two fields - results and timestamp. I don't have to re-declare them on the class level do I?

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in morphia? Did you try to create the same query with the normal mongo syntax and run it in mongo?

Comment: Ok stopping morphia from serialising Result (i.e. retrieve only timestamp which is the only field I need) helped a lot. So I guess it took forever to serialise between morphia and mongo

Comment: You should run an .explain() on that query as well to make sure it's actually using the right index. It's likely your use of both a range and a sort are messing things up.